# How can i serve static files in django?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a folder `static`:

```
static
-->css
----> main.css
-->images
----> image.png
```

`Settings.py`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_cdn")
```

I ran `collectstatic`

Now I have in `static_cdn`: `images`, `css` and `admin`(never saw this last one before).
When I run my server, it still doesn't use static files.

**How can I serve my static files to my server without using apache or nginx or that kind of stuff?**

Comment: where did you deploy your app?

Comment: on digitalocean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the common DigitalOcean solution:

Create a new [space](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/) and connect to it e.g. via [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/).

Then you have access to the file storage where you basically just run `collectstatic` within the manage.py directory.

Here is a [official DigitalOcean Tutorial on deploying Django apps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)

You will need nginx when you deploy with DigitalOcean.

DigitalOcean spaces work with Amazon S3 Bucket behind the scenes, so you might directly set up a bucket and use this, but for me there is no benefit to go the hard way. Just use the DigitalOcean `Space` since this is perfectly linked to your `droplet`.

Comment: Do I have to write an extra term for my privacy policy if I use spaces?

Comment: to be honest personally I would always set up a privacy policy, no matter if you save user data or not. This topic is so crucial meanwhile. Just get one from a generator or such to get started. Ah you dont have to mention spaces in particular within your privacy policy as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't serve static files in production but it keeps link to them. Here is where a django app called whitenoise comes to rescue when your debug is false on production.
install whitenoise on your django app:
`pip install whitenoise` then
`pip freeze > requirements.txt`
after this add this middleware to your django project settings

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

then add this line

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

then push this code to your production server and make sure you run `collectstatic` command i.e `python manage.py collectstatic`
your static files now should be working.

Answer (score 0):

For storing static files in production, you're going to need something like S3 bucket or  some other kind of external storage. I like to use whitenoise when I deploy to Heroku, since it's very simple to use. Here's an example of the configuration:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

]

# ...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```